# Update Google Play Services on Moto 360 with Chromebook (V1)

Tags: google-play-services, android-wear, chromebook, motorola-moto-360

I have a Motorola Moto 360 running Android Wear. I want to install Facer. I need to turn on ADB over WiFi or at least install a new Google Play Services, but I am using a Chromebook.

It only shows Debug over Bluetooth. I tried random IP addresses, I even used Fing to figure it out, but it doesn't show up.

How to update Play Services on Moto 360?

Comment: Sorry but all your sentences don't seem to have a relation to each other. Thus I really don't understand what you are asking for, Please rewrite your question and describe what you are trying to do and what is the problem.

Comment: @Robert I tried salvaging it based on [the same question cross-posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77038445/i-need-to-turn-on-adb-over-wifi-or-at-least-install-a-new-google-play-services). The title there gave additional context.

Comment: I still dont understand it :-)

Comment: Assuming you can enable WiFI on your Moto 360 watch: https://en-us.support.motorola.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/107038 (and realize that there are at least 2 version of the Moto 360, I'm assuming you are using the newer one) and follow: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/debugging#wifi-debugging if you aren't able to connect via your Chromebook, it may be your Chromebook, https://chromeos.dev/en/android-environment/deploying-apps As written details are missing of what you've tried.

Comment: Its moto 360 Version 1

Comment: If your device is truly this version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moto_360_(1st_generation), from what I remember that first generation of devices required a pairing app on the phone to install faces/apps. This may be your problem: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/moto-360-wont-update-4-4w-2.3205417/ But knowing what version of Android Wear OS it is running would be helpful.

Comment: the android wear version is 6.1.1